# How to install texlive-full 2015 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, latex

I see that the packages has been outdated in Ubuntu

- [Package: texlive-full (2013.20140215-1) [universe]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-full) about the current package which seems to be texlive 2013
- a vanilla way recommended to be installed in Ubuntu in the thread [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu). Vanilla way instructions are in the thread [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/13173).

I just opened my new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and did `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` and noticed that a lot of compilation errors. It would be great to get a basic typography standard in Ubuntu LTS.

---

How can you install texlive-full 2015 as a standard way in Ubuntu LTS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04, just do `sudo apt install texlive-full`. 
I think you need to compile and configure texlive-full for Ubuntu 14.04 if not found in `apt`.